# auto cargado de datos con mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Estoy cargando datos a una base en Mysql de forma automatica con un dispositivo arduino, en mi vista estoy mostrando estos datos, por medio de de una consulta en mi controlador

```
public function show($id)
{
   $consumes = consume::where('user_id', $id)->get();
   foreach ($consumes as $consume){
       $fechas = $consume->created_at;
       }
       dd($fechas);
      return view('user.consumo.show', [
        'consumes'=>$consumes
        ]);
}
```

estoy trabajando con laravel 5.5 instalé el complemento carbon ya que necesito de forma automatica insertar datos por fechas el problema es que en fechas no guarda todos las fechas solo la ultima, ¿saben el porque y como puedo guardar todas?

Comment: El error es bastante sencillo, en cada iteración reasignas el valor a la variable `$fechas` intenta con `consume::where('user_id', $id)->pluck('created_at')`  y recuerda la convención de nombres el modelo debe iniciar en mayúscula. `Consume`

Comment: gracias! no estaba utilizando la query de forma correcta.